# Correct use of key property React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So usually it's obvious to me how to use the key property.

```
const test = [1,2,3,4,5];
return (
    <>
        {test.map(x => <div key={x.toString()}>{x}</div>)}
    </>
);
```

But how is the correct way to do it if my map function looks like this:

```
const mapNumbers = (x: number) => (
<>
  <div>{x}</div>
  <div>{x+2}</div>
</>
)
```

Since I'm now mapping to two divs I'm not sure how to handle the key property here.

Comment: I think that you still can use the x as key here

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments

Comment: Thats perfect thank you very much @marzelin

Comment: @charlietfl according to docs, no. You have to use long version: `<React.Fragment key={mykey}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're mapping a list of unique numbers, you can wrap everything into a container `React.Fragment` ([details](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments)).

```js
const mapNumbers = (x: number) => (
    <React.Fragment key={x}> 
        <div>{x}</div>
        <div>{x + 2}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Edit: With `React.Fragment` as suggested by [@marzelin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5664434/marzelin).

Comment: it's better to use a keyed fragment

Comment: This was just a simplified example of my actual use... I can't wrap it in another div because of styling and layout reasons

Comment: Absolutely agree: 1) it answers the question and 2) it avoids inserting a redundant `div` element.